# Can I buy one time membership of iCloud to backup my mac?

Tags: macos, backup

I was going to buy an external hard drive to backup my mac to upgrade to macos sierra , but I was wondering if I could back it up with iCloud (200gb) account, then download it back to my mac paying just $3? Is it possible?

Comment: Why should this not be possibly? You won‘t be able tonbackup your whole Mac, but for just your documents etc. it should be ok

Comment: I think the (interesting) question is: If you pay for increased iCloud assets, how soon can you revert to the free iCloud amount?

Comment: I'd definitely temper the enthusiasm for short-term iCloud storage with the small consideration of how long it will take you to upload 200GB.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't backup your Mac with iCloud (via Time Machine).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review